# how to move footer up nd down in layout

Tags: javascript, android, virtual-keyboard

I am doing an android app where I have two buttons which should be placed in bottom and when keyboard pops up they need to move above the layout of keyboard and again go back to bottom of page. How?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `android:windowSoftInputMode` attribute of the `activity` element in your AndroidManifest.  In my application I use this code:

```
<activity android:name="MyActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
          android:launchMode="singleInstance"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

Note the `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` line.  Read more here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to display on top of the screen then you may want to consider using RelativeLayout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<com.admob.android.ads.AdView
      android:id="@+id/ad" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:backgroundColor="#000000"
      app:primaryTextColor="#FFFFFF"
      app:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    />

<!-- TextView below that -->

<TextView
android:id="@+id/widget28"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Input Amount:"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
android:layout_below="@id/ad"
android:textSize="16dip"
android:textStyle="bold">
</TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```